# Is there a way to weaken the permissions of the apps I create on Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I created the app on Azure AD.

The application works fine.

By the way, I wanted to make this app's permissions smaller.

First, I want to limit the schedule that this app can view. 
For example, the application can see user A's schedule, but not user B's schedule, and so on. User A and User B are registered on the same Azure AD.

Second, I want to limit the users who can impersonate themselves as email senders.
For example, user C can send a mail, but user D can't send a mail.

Is there a better way to do it?

[image: This is the app's permissions.]

Thank you.

Comment: This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access. Exchange specifically has some things available to restrict app-only access. In the general case application permissions cannot be limited.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @juunas suggested, Microsoft Graph Application permissions can't be limited. It is for the entire tenant.

But you can use [New-ApplicationAccessPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/organization/new-applicationaccesspolicy?view=exchange-ps) to restrict your app to target mailboxes.

For example:

```
New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AccessRight RestrictAccess -AppId "{appID}" -PolicyScopeGroupId EvenUsers@AppPolicyTest2.com -Description "Restrict this app to members of security group EvenUsers."
```

You can put user A and C into the security group EvenUsers. Then your app is only granted access to the data of user A and C.