# Microsoft GRAPH api - restrict user access

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I have created a azure APP and I have given "Mail.ReadBasic.All" to this APP. With this we can access metadata for all mailboxes. I want to restrict this access to only one email address. Basically REST call only allowing metadata to be retrieved for only one target email.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

- Implement [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) and the app will only
  access the signed-in user's mailbox and any other mailboxes the user
  have access to.
- If you are using [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service), you could use
  [New-ApplicationAccessPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/organization/new-applicationaccesspolicy?view=exchange-ps) to restrict your app to target
  mailboxes. For example: `New-ApplicationAccessPolicy -AccessRight RestrictAccess -AppId "{appID}" -PolicyScopeGroupId EvenUsers@AppPolicyTest2.com -Description "Restrict this app to members of security group EvenUsers."`

See a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60830472/is-there-a-way-to-weaken-the-permissions-of-the-apps-i-create-on-azure-ad/60842835#60842835).